# Custom package development: Basic steps

Tags: packages, development

Every once in a while, I write a generic function that I use quite often for months to come. However, package development in Mathematica is not very well documented from what I can tell, and I was not able to find a coherent description online (most of them deal with tiny issues and bits). In the end, I usually give up and copy+paste the function in every new notebook, which isn't really the way to go.

Does anyone here develop packages himself and could walk me from "open Mathematica" to "save as something that can be included via `` <<Package` ``" or give me a good reference?