# Mathematica Library

Tags: mathematical-optimization, packages, code-generation

I created a Mathematica packagr and then I used the Needs function to add the library to my .nb file, but when use a function in my .nb file and the function is built in my library it comes up with the functions output multiplied by "mylibraryname`Private`".

My Package:

```
BeginPackage["Afak10`"] 
Unprotect @@ Names["Afak10`*"]; 
ClearAll @@ Names["Afak10`*"]; 
f::usage = "f[x]" 
Begin["Private"] 
f[x_] := Module[{}, x^2 + s]; 
End[] 
Protect @@ Names["Afak10`*"]; 
EndPackage[]
```

Output:

```
Afak10`Private`s + x^2
```

What if I define f[x] as:

```
f[x_] := Module[{asdfs},asdfs];
```

The Output is:

```
Afak10`Private`asdfs$4980
```

Comment: You need to give a more concrete example of your functions and how you are using them.  I can think of a few different possible causes for this but I don't feel like explaining problems that don't exist.

Comment: Well its a big package with many functions, some of them are fine and others aren't

Comment: If you want help, then find a simple case: make up a small package that has the same problem. Then we can try and help.

Comment: Take this library for example:

Comment: BeginPackage["Afak10`"] 
Unprotect @@ Names["Afak10`*"]; 
ClearAll @@ Names["Afak10`*"];
f::usage = "f[x]"
Begin["`Private`"]
f[x_] := Module[{}, x^2 + s];
End[]
Protect @@ Names["Afak10`*"];
EndPackage[]

Comment: When every I call f(x) I get

Comment: Afak10`Private`s + x^2

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7502/862)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [How do I create and use Mathematica packages?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9567)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have a Symbol `s` that is not declared before the line `Begin` line.  Because of this it is created in that specified `` Afak10`Private` `` context.  (Also, your code presently has an error; it needs to be `` Begin["Private`"] ``.)  You can include the `` Global` `` context if that is in fact the Symbol you wish to return:

```
f[x_] := Module[{}, x^2 + Global`s];  (* as part of your package *)
```

Now using the function:

```
f[z]
```

> ```
> s + z^2
> ```

Nevertheless I caution you about this method as you generally should not use (plain) global Symbols like this; instead use [Formal Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) which are [`Protected`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Protected.html) to prevent accidental assignment.

```
f[x_] := Module[{}, x^2 + \[FormalS]];
```

It looks like this:

[image]