# Package relative file path specification

Tags: packages

I have some packages inside a folder (named Packs) that is in the same file level of some executed package.

```
executedPack.m
Packs/subPack01.m
Packs/subPack02.m
Packs/subPack03.m
```

Today I use this structure do load the sub packages inside the executedPack.m:

```
(*Execution without Front-End*) 
Needs["MyPack`",FileNameJoin[{DirectoryName@$InputFileName,"Packs","subPack01.m"}]]

(*Execution with Front-End*)    
Needs["MyPack`",FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"Packs","subPack01.m"}]]
```

The first I use when running the package without front-end, and the last when I evaluate in the front-end.

There is some simpler way to do that, more symmetric? I read some kernel folder structure, but I didn't find more details on that.

### Update

Now what I want, but better. This works both in Fron-End and no Front-End execution.

```
Quiet[Check[SetDirectory@DirectoryName@$InputFileName,SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]],SetDirectory::fstr];
Needs["Packs`subPack01`"];
```

Comment: For a start you could look at:  [Custom Package Development](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/303/custom-package-development-basic-steps/11424#11424)

Comment: Interesting David, tks.

Answer (score 5):

You you could use the following code in place of your example above.

```
Needs["MyPack`", FileNameJoin[{
   If[$InputFileName == "", NotebookDirectory[], $InputFileName]
   , "Packs", "subPack01.m"}]]
```

Or you could use `Module` like the following.

```
Module[{$InputFileName = 
       If[$InputFileName == "", NotebookDirectory[], $InputFileName]},
     Print[$InputFileName];
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

After some google and forum search, I get this:

```
Quiet@SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
Needs["Packs`subPack01`"];
```

To avoid alert msg, `subPack01` is declared inside it as:

```
BeginPackage["Packs`subPack01`"]
```

[this is a nice article](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/303/custom-package-development-basic-steps/11424#11424), tks @DavidPark for the reference